# Class variables - missing one required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two scripts. The first containing a class, with class variables defined and a function using those class variables. The second script calls the class and function within a function of it's own.

This sort of set up works fine for functions inside a class, however adding class variables is causing me the below error. Can anyone explain why, please and what I need to do to fix?

Thanks

obj1.py:

```
class my_test_class():

    def __init__(self):

        self.test1 = 'test1'
        self.test2 = 'test2'
        self.test3 = 'test3'

    def test_func(self, var):

        new_var = print(var, self.test1, self.test2, self.test3)
```

obj2.py

```
from obj1 import *


def import_test():

    target_var = my_test_class.test_func('my test is:')
    print(target_var)

import_test()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python27/Test/obj2.py", line 9, in <module>
    import_test()
  File "G:/Python27/Test/obj2.py", line 6, in import_test
    target_var = my_test_class.test_func('my test is:')
TypeError: test_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'var'
```

Comment: You didn't create an instance of `my_test_class` before trying to call an instance method (since `test_func` expects `self`)

Comment: Separately, `my_test_class` should be `MyTestClass` and you should avoid `*` imports. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). This convention is actually really important for others to understand your code and avoid bugs.

Comment: Create an instance `test_class = my_test_class()` and then call `test_class.test_func('my test is:')`

Comment: hi. thanks all. yes, that fixed my problem. always get a bit confused with this issue...

Comment: Hi @gdogg371, I have tried to put the comments from above into an answer, please take a look below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commentors have pointed out, since the `test_func` is a class method, we need to call it using a class instance object.

Also `print` function returns None, so doing `new_var = print(var, self.test1, self.test2, self.test3)` assigns `new_var=None`, so if you want to return the variable, you need to assign `new_var = ' '.join([var, self.test1, self.test2, self.test3])`, which creates a string with a whitespace between all the words, and `return new_var`

Combining all of this, the code comes out as follows

```
class my_test_class():

    def __init__(self):

        self.test1 = 'test1'
        self.test2 = 'test2'
        self.test3 = 'test3'

    def test_func(self, var):

        #Assign value to new_var and return it
        new_var = ' '.join([var, self.test1, self.test2, self.test3])
        return new_var

def import_test():

    #Create instance of my_test_class
    test_class = my_test_class()
    #Call test_func using instance of my_test_class
    print(test_class.test_func('my test is:'))

import_test()
```

The output will be `my test is: test1 test2 test3`